# Two product layout in magento

Tags: magento, layout, product

In magento project, I have four categories and I have 2 template file for products

Like

1) catalog/product/view.phtml    (original)

2) catalog/product/newview.phtml  (new file)

Now I want to display product layout based on category

like category id 1 and 2, product display base on view.phtml

and category 3 and 4, product display based on newview.phtml

Answer (score 0):

You can set this on each product in the backend in the design tab set :

```
<reference name="product.info">
     <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/newview.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

Else you can also perform this through an Observer to get all product from category X in one shot.

Create your own module observing the `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after` event with a function like this one :

```
public function generateBlocksAfter($event)
{                      
    $controller   = $event->getAction();
//limit to the product view page 
if($controller->getFullActionName() != 'catalog_product_view')
{
    return;
}
$layout       = $controller->getLayout();
$product_info = $layout->getBlock('product.info');
if(!$product_info)
{
     Mage::log('Could not find product.info block');
     return;
 }
$id = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
$prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$category_ids = $prod->getCategoryIds();
if(in_array(3,$category_ids) || in_array(4,$category_ids))     
     $product_info->setTemplate('catalog/product/newview.phtml');
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me this is the right way for adding observed?

local(dir)
 --> Mage (dir)
   --> Catalog (dir)
      == Modal (dir)
         --> Observer.php (File)
      == etc (dir)
         --> config.xml

======= Observer.php =======
class Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer
{
   public function generateBlocksAfter($event){.....}
}
======= config.xml ======
<frontend>
  <events>
    <controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after>
      <observers>
        ....
      </observers>
    </controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after>
  </events>
</frontend>

Comment: I suggest to set this in a module of your own not in Mage_Catalog, but yes it seems to be the right approach

Answer (score 0):

use this code for display according to categories id in local.xml files

```
      <reference name="product_list">
          <action method="setTemplate"><name>catalog/product/list_new.phtml</name></action>
      </reference>
 </CATEGORY_5>
```